# SQL Select a column field without adding additional column

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a table named DEPOSITS with columns amount, date and time. Lets say I want to select all the columns of DEPOSITS and add in an additional column named Data source with the values deposits. Can I do this without altering the actual database table column?

So my select query output will be like

Table Deposits

---

```
amount date      time  dataSource
1000   1/1/2017  5am   Deposits 
2000   2/1/2017  10pm  Deposits
```

Note that I don't wish to alter the table to insert a column dataSource. I just want to select it as shown. Please help thanks!

Comment: I think this question should not answer its a very basic of SQL fundamentals. this question should remove immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
select amount, date, time, 'Deposits' as dataSource
from Deposits
```